# Please tell me any way to view Django website on android

Tags: python, android, django, cmd

I am developing a django framework based website using python and i want to test it on an android device ,
the tutorials on youutube to launch via computer seems not to work for me so please tell me any way to launch or see website on my android mobile

Comment: Maybe pressing F12 and the the mobile icon on the left top corner. There you can see the website in a mobile-like display.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try heroku?  Its easy to use.try it.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy,
Make sure both your PC and mobile are connected to the same **wifi**

then open cmd and type ***ipconfig*** 
and copy the ***IPv4 Address*** (which is your local IP address)

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Home
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1dd0:69ed:a1b:f4e6%21
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.7 <-- this address
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0 
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::ca3a:35ff:fe6e:b4f8%21
                                       192.168.10.1
```

after that open ***settings.py***
and add that IP Address to ALLOWED_HOSTS

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["192.168.10.7"]
```

now you have to run the server by typing this address -> 0.0.0.0:[ANY PORT]

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 #you can set any other port instead of 8000
```

and you're all set.
open any browser on your mobile phone and type this URL:

```
[YOUR_IP_ADDRESS]:[PORT]

OR,

192.168.10.7:8000
```

Your PC and mobile phone must be connected to the same network(LAN).

Comment: it doesnt work for me please tell  any other method\

Comment: Maybe your network is not private in windows.To make it private, go to -> Settings -> Network & Internet -> Wifi -> click on connected wifi -> change the network profile to private.Also, disable the Firewall and check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://ngrok.com/docs, you have to set the port that your server is running (probably 8000, Django default port) then ngrok will generate a link to you access anywhere.

Best Regards!